# How to take input as json string and later convert it to any object based on condition

Tags: json, go

Here I want to take DefaultResponse as String but later validate if it's a valid json before mapping to any json struct.

**Complete code with validation can be found here :**
https://go.dev/play/p/knGNMj1QG3l

```
type AddEndpointRequest struct {
    Method            string `json:"method"`
    ContentType       int    `json:"contentType"`
    DefaultStatusCode int    `json:"defaultStatusCode"`
    DefaultResponse   string `json:"defaultResponse"`
}
```

I tried different option but none of them are working

1. if I pass this : “defaultResponse”:{“title”:“Buy cheese and bread for breakfast.”}
   Getting error : json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field AddEndpointRequest.defaultResponse of type string
2. 

body := `{"method":"GET","contentType":1,"defaultWaitTimeInMillis":100,"defaultStatusCode":200,"defaultResponse":"[{"p":"k"}]"}`

Error : invalid character 'p' after object key:value pair

3)
body := `{"method":"GET","contentType":1,"defaultWaitTimeInMillis":100,"defaultStatusCode":200,"defaultResponse":"`{"p":"k"}`"}`
./prog.go:21:117: syntax error: unexpected { at end of statement

4. body := `{"method":"GET","contentType":1,"defaultWaitTimeInMillis":100,"defaultStatusCode":200,"defaultResponse":"{/"p/":/"k/"}`"} `Error : ./prog.go:21:130: syntax error: unexpected literal "}` at end of statement

And many more

Comment: Option 4 would work if you escape your quotes properly using \ instead of /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option A:**

Declare the field as a string. Use a valid JSON string as the field value in the document. Note the escaping of the quotes in the string.

```
type AddEndpointRequest struct {
    Method            string          `json:"method"`
    ContentType       int             `json:"contentType"`
    DefaultStatusCode int             `json:"defaultStatusCode"`
    DefaultResponse   string          `json:"defaultResponse"`
}
…
body := `{"method":"GET","contentType":1,"defaultWaitTimeInMillis":100,"defaultStatusCode":200,"defaultResponse":"{\"p\":\"k\"}"}`
```

Convert the field to a []byte to unmarshal:

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(request.DefaultResponse), &data)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/ailgQQ3eQBH

**Option B:**

Declare the field as json.RawMessage. Use any valid JSON in the document.

```
type AddEndpointRequest struct {
    Method            string          `json:"method"`
    ContentType       int             `json:"contentType"`
    DefaultStatusCode int             `json:"defaultStatusCode"`
    DefaultResponse   json.RawMessage `json:"defaultResponse"`
}
…
body := `{"method":"GET","contentType":1,"defaultWaitTimeInMillis":100,"defaultStatusCode":200,"defaultResponse":{"p":"k"}}`
```

The call to `json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &request)` validates the json.RawMessage field.  If the call to json.Unmarshal does not return an error, then the application is assured that AddEndpointRequest.DefaultResponse contains valid JSON.

Unmarshal the field like this:

```
err := json.Unmarshal(request.DefaultResponse, &data)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Xd_gWzJmvC_K

Comment: Note that using `json.RawMessage` will not validate the "JSON" it holds. It's simply a `[]byte`. https://go.dev/play/p/eGvM-11uCqB

Comment: I see what you mean. If valid JSON was present when it was parsed, then yes it'll be valid coming out. Every valid JSON can be marshalled into a json.RawMessage, but not every json.RawMessage can be unmarshalled into valid JSON.

Comment: On second glance, json.RawMessage still may not be what OP is asking for. https://go.dev/play/p/aZcEsGhFO2T Any value can be put in for `msg` as long as the whole JSON is valid, but there's no requirement that a json.RawMessage has to be an object, array, or valid JSON on its own. It's just a `[]byte`

Comment: I think I'm getting hung up on the difference between "valid JSON" and "valid JSON object." I thought OP was asking for a valid JSON object ("before mapping to any json struct" I read as "must be an object") but re-reading the question that may not be strictly the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a struct in `defaultResponse`, I think doing it like this should work.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type AddEndpointRequest struct {
    Method            string `json:"method"`
    ContentType       int    `json:"contentType"`
    DefaultStatusCode int    `json:"defaultStatusCode"`
    DefaultResponse   string `json:"defaultResponse"`
}

func main() {

    body := `{"method":"GET","contentType":1,"defaultWaitTimeInMillis":100,"defaultStatusCode":200,"defaultResponse":{"title":"Buy cheese and bread for breakfast."}}`
    fmt.Println("Hello GO")

    err := validateBody(body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("erro102")
        fmt.Println(err)

    }
}

func validateBody(body string) error {
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &data)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("invalid json body provided for the request")
    }

    fmt.Println("data===>", data)

    fmt.Println("defaultResponse===>", data["defaultResponse"].(map[string]interface{})["title"])

    return nil
}
```